# Want to load part of an array into android ListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

My code works like this to list all items in my String array - itemsarray

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,
        R.id.label, itemsarray));
```

However, I know by this call that I only want to list the first X number of items from itemsarray.  How can I load only the first X items form itemsarray into the ListAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it automatically... you will have to do it manually. You have two alternatives:

```
// the easy one:
ArrayList<String> someItems = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String element : itemsarray) // add the first 5 elements
    someItems.add(element);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, someItems));
```

Or you can create a subclass of `ArrayAdapter` and override the `getCount` method returning X. It will make the list think it just have X elements to show.

Comment: I already was using a subclass for ArrayAdapter and adding @Override public int getCount() { return X; } was exactly what the doctor ordered. Thanks again Cristian!